# Easier way to append a span tag to list element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have several list elements that look like this:

```
 <li><a href="#" id="list1">List 1 Values</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="list2">List 2 Values</a></li>
```

My current solution is to replace the entire html string like so:

```
$('#list1').html('List 1 Values<span>150</span>');
```

Is there a better way to add/remove the span tag inside a list item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#list1').append('content');
```

See [`.append()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: that was easy enough...I guess I should have tried that first :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `append` like below,

```
$('#list1').append('<span>150</span>');
```